# Confused about server-side SDK of PayPal

Tags: javascript, laravel, paypal

Currently I'm integrating PayPal payment into my project, but I'm confused about something. Everything works fine and I'm glad to see it is working, but somehow my sixth sense tells me to create a server-side SDK request instead of the current client-side. Here's what I've done so far:

```
paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
    layout:  'vertical',
    color:   'blue',
    shape:   'rect',
    label:   'pay',
}, createOrder: function(data, actions) {

        return actions.order.create({

            purchase_units: [{

            amount: {
                description: '{{ $setup->plan->name }}',
                value: '{{ $setup->plan->price }}'

            }

            }],
            application_context: {
                shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
            }

        });

}, onApprove: function(data, actions) {

    return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

        alert('successfull payment');

}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

and everything works great, but I want to create a server-side intent because I somehow feel it more secure. Can someone explain me how can I easily either check the transaction within this javascript code if it is completed successfully and the user paid the exact price for the goods or create a server-side intent for the payment so I can prevent users from manually edit the price? The documentation is way too difficult to understand for me that's why I asked my question here. My project is on **Laravel 8**

Answer (score 0):

How to do a server integration is covered within [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), in the 'Add and modify the code' section, with links to sample code.

Make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server